# Is the Day Z mod compatible with the standalone release of Day Z?

Tags: dayz-2012

I got the Day Z mod with my copy of Arma 2 in this week's Humble Bundle and I was wondering; is the modification of Arma 2 version compatible with the standalone release of Day Z?

Am I able to play with people who have the standalone release with my Arma 2 modification release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The two versions are not compatible.